# URL rewrite to remove query string

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Using IIS url rewrite how can I remove the entire query string specific to this link only

Change from

[www.domainname.com/contact/grant-application?_cldee=aXsh9oxd11cuZV7sTRg1gCXTakp_Z-YOyhl0ycu0Gipd4Z6Oh5tTrX9e772vDcf8&recipientid=contact-d16506fd0fa7e811a969002248072781-6a51eefb85b84b16987fda7b12dab220&esid=c1389cb8-c232-ed11-9db2-000d3ad4e0b8](http://www.domainname.com/contact/grant-application?_cldee=aXsh9oxd11cuZV7sTRg1gCXTakp_Z-YOyhl0ycu0Gipd4Z6Oh5tTrX9e772vDcf8&recipientid=contact-d16506fd0fa7e811a969002248072781-6a51eefb85b84b16987fda7b12dab220&esid=c1389cb8-c232-ed11-9db2-000d3ad4e0b8)

to this

[www.domainname.com/contact/grant-application](http://www.domainname.com/contact/grant-application)

Comment: Create a rewrite rule to redirect such a request to itself but without appending query string. Make sure this rule has a condition that query string isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the steps below to remove the query string using the URL Rewrite module in the IIS.

1. Select your site in the IIS and open the URL Rewrite module.
2. click on the **Add Rule(s)** option from the Actions pane located on the right side of the screen.
3. Give the **name** to the rule.
4. Select **Matches the pattern** for **Requested URL** dropdown and select **Regular Expressions** for **Using** drop down.

[image]

5. Set `(.*)` as **Pattern**.
6. Under conditions, add a new condition.
7. Set `{QUERY_STRING}` for **Condition Input**, select **Matches the pattern** option for **Check if input string** dropdown, set `\_cldee=(.*)` as **pattern**. Click OK.

[image]

8. Set **Redirect** for **Action type** dropdown.
9. Set `http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}` as **Redirect URL**.
10. Uncheck the checkbox **Append query string**.
11. Set `Permanent(301)` as **Redirect Type** drop-down.

[image]

12. Click the **Apply** button on the Actions pane. Then test your site in the browser.

**Output:**

[image]

Further, you could try to modify the rule above as per your own requirement.